# How to refactor codes in Robot Framework?

Tags: pycharm, refactoring, robotframework

I recently having issue when trying to rename/move robot files.

I'm using both Pycharm & IntelliJ IDE

I tried to rename (or move) robot files into new name (or new directory in the project) using Shift + F6 command

The filename is changed by the way, but the Import Section in each file does not change at all, it keeps the previous value, for example:

```
Resource       ../../../../keywords/common/common_web_keywords.robot
```

Is there any way (or plugins) to deal with this issue?

Thank you!

Comment: I can't comment for Eclipse's ecosystem, but the plugins for PyCharm, plus the IDE itself **do not** handle file rename fully - they do not change the name in the imports, like here. You have to do it manually/by hand; in PyCharm just use the key shortcut "Ctrl|Command + Shift + R" for global replace.